Adding customers to a subscription using the API
We have subscriptions that contain two products. One is a monthly flat fee, and the other fee is based on metered usage.
I have successfully created such a subscription using the dashboard, and have been able to add a couple of hundred metered usage counts using the API.
My question is about creating another subscription for a new user (using the API). Do I need to create the entire subscription using the API, or is there a way to create the subscription using the dashboard, and then use the API to add new customers to the same subscription?

You can create a Subscription either via API or Dashboard (as you already did).
However, you will need to specify a Customer when create it (meaning you will need to create a new Customer in prior to creating a new Subscription). You can't do the otherwise of create a Subscription without a Customer first, then associate with a Customer later.

Thanks. Yes, my code already creates the customer. Do I need to create a new subscription for each customer?

Yes, a Subscription per a Customer
